# Docker Image: How to add Maven dependencies for offline usage?

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile

I would lIke to ask how to add (copy) the Maven project dependencies to maven docker image (https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) which is running during the CI/CD in the sandbox without access to the internet?

I tried the following approach but it seems not to be working.  The dependencies are stored in the ~/.m2 directory.  Is a better approach to copy dependency folders to Maven image or use the following: command for copy project .pom file in the Dockerfile?

```
RUN mvn -B -f /tmp/pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml dependency:resolve
```

Many Thanks for any advice.

```
# Pull base image.
FROM library/maven
############################

# Install Dependencies
#COPY pom.xml /tmp/pom.xml
RUN pwd
ADD  repository /usr/share/maven/ref/repository
#RUN mvn -B -f /tmp/pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml dependency:resolve
#RUN mvn clean install -o 
#RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

# Define default command.
#CMD ["bash"]

############################
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run maven in offline mode mvn -o install